# Want to buy small as in volume as in litres/centimetres USB solid-state drive (overspecification: USB flash drive) with power/activity indicator light

Tags: usb, ssd, led, flash-drive

I currently (2023‑11‑26) use a Corsair Flash Voyager Slider 128GB USB 3.0 (CMFSL3B-128GB) model of USB solid-state drive (overspecification: USB flash drive because it could use a different type of non-volatile memory, such as ferroelectric RAM, which is already used commercially but still costs much more per unit of memory than (NAND) flash memory) because this model has a power/activity indicator light, which is a hard requirement for me, and is reliable because I have been using it since I bought it new from Amazon in 2014 but this drive makes my wallet thick when I carry the drive in my wallet because the drive is approximately 12 mm thick as in top to bottom, approximately 7 cm long as in from the end of the full-size USB Type A plug to the opposite end and approximately 23 mm wide.  Much smaller as in volume as in litres, not storage capacity, models of USB SSDs are available but I do not want any of them that I have found so far because they lack a power/activity indicator light.  Here is an example model that is barely larger than the full-size USB Type A connector on the drive:

[SanDisk 32GB Cruzer Fit USB 2.0 Flash Drive (SDCZ33-032G-G35)](https://www.newegg.ca/sandisk-model-sdcz33-032g-g35-32gb/p/N82E16820173256)

Is there any small as in volume as in litres, not storage capacity, preferably at least 128 GB and SuperSpeed USB but the at least 128 GB part is more important than having faster than High-speed USB connectivity, model of USB SSD that I can currently acquire that has a power/activity indicator light?

The PriceSpy.co.nz Web site has a filter for models of drives with a light but none of the drives in the micro size as in volume as in litres category have a light.

I do not want to carry the drive loose in my pants pocket because then it would have to go in my left pants pocket, which already contains too many items:

- two pens so that if I leave one behind I still have one
- Chinese Army Knife (Chinese as in the PRoC so the People’s Liberation Army I suppose)
- keyring with nine keys for everything except my car (edit: down to only six keys as of 2023‑11‑26)
- keyring for my car that has the key separate from the wireless remote control.  I wish the key fit together with the remote control like some other models of vehicles have but both of the cars I have had so far, including the current one, have the key separate from the remote control.  My first car was a 1998 Volkswagen New Beetle GLS TDI and my current car is a 2010 Hyundai Elantra Touring GLS SE (Sport Edition), both with 5-speed manual transmission.

My right pants pocket contains my handheld computer and my wallet, nothing else because I cannot put anything that could scratch my handheld computer in the same pocket as my handheld computer.  So I prefer to keep my USB SSD in my wallet instead of having another thing in my left pants pocket.